# Can sandwiching an invertible matrix change the rank or null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose $M \succ 0$ and we have some matrix $X$ such that rank($X'X) = r$. Then is rank($X'MX ) = r$, and can we relate the null spaces of $X'X$ and $X'MX$ in any way?

Since multiplication by an invertible matrix doesn't change the rank of the original matrix, I think the rank is preserved. But I can't seem to directly relate the null spaces, which was my initial attempt at proving this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints.

1. If $X$ is a square matrix, then $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(X'X)$ (why?)
2. $\operatorname{Ker}(X)\subset \operatorname{Ker}(X'X)$.
3. From 1 and 2 it follows that $\operatorname{Ker}(X)=\operatorname{Ker}(X'X)$.
4. $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(X'X)=\operatorname{rank}(X'MX)$.
5. $\operatorname{Ker}(X)\subset \operatorname{Ker}(X'MX)$.
6. It follows from 4 and 5 that $\operatorname{Ker}(X)=\operatorname{Ker}(X'MX)$.
7. Thus $\operatorname{Ker}(X'X)=\operatorname{Ker}(X'MX)$.

**Addition.**
Here's a simple reasoning proving equality of ranks.
If $X$ is a diagonal matrix, the equality $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(X'X)$ is obvious. Let $S$ be a non-singular matrix such that $XS$ is diagonal
(you certainly know how to find $S$).
We get
$$
\operatorname{rank}(X'X)
=\operatorname{rank}(S'X'XS)
=\operatorname{rank}(XS)'(XS)
=\operatorname{rank}(XS)
=\operatorname{rank}(X).
$$
In a similar way we can also prove
$$
\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(X'MX)
$$
provided that $M\succ0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I proved 1-3 and 4-6 directly by showing the kernels of the respective matrix are equal (so by the rank nullity theorem, since $X$ is square, the ranks must be equal). For example $Ker(X) \subset Ker(X'MX)$ is straightforward, and if $X'MXv = 0$, then $v'X'MXv = |(M^{1/2}Xv|^2 = 0$, so $Xv = 0$. 
Is there another way to show that the ranks are equal?

Comment: @gwtw14
Of course, there is another way. I made an addition to my answer. But your way is also wonderful.